# How might extreme tides affect the evolution of life?

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology, fauna, tides

I was hypothesizing about making a planet with a different path of evolution. A planet with dominant species being more akin to amphibians albeit further down the evolutionary chain. Would extreme tides have that effect? like say miles long, or would those tides wreck the continents too much? How might these extreme tides influence that evolution?

Maybe a 1000ft height difference. Probably a slower tide so that it doesn't cause 1000ft high tidal waves. So like a tide that goes all the way out and all the way in like 3 or 4 times a year or so

Comment: What is an extreme tide for you? Can you attach a number to it?

Comment: There are [places on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadden_Sea) where the intertidal zone extends for *many* miles, and nobody thinks that the tides there are extreme. (And here on Earth very very few amphibians live in sea water, so we have no idea how the tides would affect them.)

Comment: let's say 1000ft height difference. Probably a slower tide so that it doesn't cause 1000ft high tidal waves. So like a tide that goes all the way out and all the way in like 3 or 4 times a year perhaps

Comment: True that we don't have salt water amphibians on earth now, but evolutionarily amphibians led to the land animals we have today. I'm kind of looking for a way to extend those same conditions that amphibians evolved from, but stretch them out much farther so that there is more evolutionary reason for breathing both water and air

Comment: Edit that info in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: well, if the tides were variable around the year, leaving bodies of water, yet having times in the year were there is no water, the dominant species would be aquatic or amphibian as they'd wouldn't need constant land if the tides hit the continent in a fully continuous cycle, the main species would be aquatic, since land dwelling is not safe for the most part

Comment: So amphibian life would be more prominent if there were variable bodies of water and bigger tides, rather than just insane tides constantly?

Comment: Gonna be difficult to do higher tides that Earth had, back when the Moon was young. 600m (yes meter, not inch) tides, back when the moon was 1/18th the distance from Earth.

Comment: 1000ft tide is not just going to move water, that much gravitational potential is going to knead the planet like dough drastically heating it up.

Comment: @Ithurien yes, imagine this: a part of the planet is covered in water, then most disappears, if you do not have legs or a way to survive outside the water, you die, and the other way around, while if land is constantly hit by tsunamis every day, land animals would drown, etc. but fish could live in the depths, were it is "safer" and survive, and so on, also the plant life would be different, a mixture of trees and algae, able to live underwater yet survive on dry climates

sorry if it made it more confusing- my fault

Answer (score 1):

We don’t have examples of this tide pattern on Earth to cite, but I suggest we can extrapolate from other highly variable environments. Deserts that have a monsoon season or arctic regions with extreme temperature/light swings... in all these environments, we see huge ranges of species with **dormancy**. If all the tidal regions where life advances significantly is so extremely variable, I would expect most life forms would have adaptations for hibernation or stasis or cocooning. In tide regions on Earth, we have plants that fold up while the tide is out and animals that retreat to burrows while the tide comes in. More extreme versions of those would be my extrapolation.